# How can I display a still image / short video loop through a webcam?

Tags: google-chrome, webcam

I need to sneak away from my desk without the person I'm video chatting realising.

I am staying pretty still, and she's working so not that observant. I think a still image would fool her for long enough.

I'm currently trying hanging an image in front, but she caught onto that when my sister drew on the image:

Before
                                                                           
After

[image][image]

How can I "pause" what my webcam is sending to her, so I can leave it. If she thinks I've frozen that's fine - although maybe playing a loop of me moving slightly would be even better.

I'm using Google Chrome and Hangouts, so if something can be done at the software level, to trick it, that would be good.

Is there some way I can use the terminal to create a "phantom" webcam, that simply displays an image I've got saved on my computer?

Could `/dev/video1` or whatever just be an image?

I'd also be interested if I could cannibalise an old webcam to do this and trick the computer, and her.

<sup>P.S. I was in trouble when she realised.</sup>

Comment: Keep that picture forever and remind your sister of that picture whenever she needs: a drive, money, you faking an excuse for her not to get into trouble, ...  **>:-)**